# angular watch on object and it's child

Tags: angularjs

I have an on object in my directive, let's say:

```
scope = {
    A : { 
       B : [],
       C : 5
    }
}

scope.$watch('A', function aWasChanged(){});
scope.$watchCollection('B', function bWasChanged(){});
```

I have a watch on A and on B. But when A is changed the watch of B is called as well. What I want is that when A is changed only "aWasChanged" will be called (even if B was changed as well) and "bWasChanged" will be called only when B is changed.

Comment: How are you changing A? Since B in an attribute of A, assigning a new value to A would change B, so both watches would fire

Comment: I think it won't be easy to fire 'only B has changed' because as @hassassin said, B is child of A. You could write your own comparison function to get the correct info. I made a simple plunker to work with: http://plnkr.co/edit/wsPdCHELKByqAPeZIZWs?p=preview using watch with the objectEquality parameter to `true`.

Comment: In your example "changeA" actually changes property of A, what I mean by changeA is change the entire object A = {B: ..., C: ...}; This triggers B's change callback as well which is logical because B was changed as well. But I don't want B's callback to be called.

Comment: You mean that you don't want B's callback to be called even if B has really been changed `(newvalue !== oldValue)`? If so, why?

Comment: Because it's either only B was changed or entire A was changed. In the first case I want to do one thing (let's call it B-thing) and in the second case I want to do something else (let's call it A-thing). When A is changed I don't need B-thing to happen.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean under `A` is changed.

Generally the `$watch()` only checks object reference equality but not structure.

For example if you will write something like:

```
$scope.A.ddd = "ddd";
```

the `$watch` will do not catch that.

However *deep-watch* (with flag `true`) should take care about this case.

> when A is changed only "aWasChanged" will be called...

I suppose you mean if `C` will change ... so write your custom comparator like:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
       return $scope.A;
    },
    function (newValue, oldValue) {

     if(newValue.C == oldValue.C){return;} // avoid B

     /*...*/

    }, true); // Object equality (not just reference).
```

The *deep-watch* a bit expensive so like you wrote will be good way:

```
scope.$watchCollection('A.B', function bWasChanged(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to do something like

```
$scope.foo.A = {
  B: [],
  C: 6
};
```

and have the watch on A fire but not on the B fire, you could always hack how angular is indexing it.

```
var key = $scope.foo.A.B.$$hashKey;
$scope.foo.A = {
  B: [],
  C: 6
};
$scope.foo.A.B.$$hashKey = key;
```

Here is an updated plnkr with that http://plnkr.co/edit/hAY9pb3AUAF0drAm42A5?p=preview.